# Cleaning up self-answered questions

Tags: discussion

Recently I posted a [ridiculously long question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885288/io-exception-error-when-using-serialport-open-serialport/15508843#15508843) about a `SerialPort` issue. I chronicled the events in decent detail and after about a month of screwing up I finally found the issue and posted my answer on the now wiki'd question.

What I want to know is should I go through, summarize the issue and the answer and get rid of the rest of the 'non-essentials'? Some of the comments might not make as much sense and (maybe not in this case) sometimes the other answers don't make any sense if there is too much pruning.

What is the etiquette in this situation? Do I leave it as is? Or simplify it as much as possible? And what about other people's posts? Wiki posts? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I removed wiki from the question and your answer, since it's really not necessary there.

I suggest cleaning up the question to incorporate all the edits into a single, coherent description of what happened and your debugging steps. Then leave your solution ("curse you, firmware!") in your answer.

Comments can be flagged to be cleaned up as obsolete.

Comment: I will definitely add 'curse you firmware!' in my answer. I yelled it when I found out, the least I can do is share it with the coding world.